# Basic Caesars Code; encrypt string. Please explain what i did :D

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

The task is to encrypt the sentence: " My hovercraft is full of eels."
I missed the exercise class due to other duties ;) 
Anyway i came to an result made of sniplets i found on the internet and a bit of experimenting. it goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{

int i=0;
char str[]="My hovercraft is full of eels.";
char c;
while (str[i])     //While String is true (Still characters left)
{
    if (str[i]!='z')   //if character is NOT "z" shift character by one
        {
    (c=str[i]+1);
        }
    else {
            (c=str[i]='a'); //if character equals "z" then the output is "a"
        }


    printf("%c" ,c);  // Shows encrypted string
    i++;
  }
return 0;
}
```

My problem is i dont know what i really did. Could someone explain my code? :D

First i introduce the integer i which is =0 
then a string of characters
and the variable c which is a character as well.
while there are character left in the string add 1 if it is not equal to z
otherwise c equals a. so z = a
but i honestly dont know why it needs i++ which i copied from a far more complex caesars code. so thats it.

Comment: If you don't know what this code means then you probably haven't written it (or it doesn't work). Anyway, create a step by step description of the algorithm from Wikipedia and try to look for those steps in your code. The instructor requires you to explain your code in order to check if you actually wrote it, because you have to understand the concepts of what you write in order to write it.

Comment: Please don't use magic numbers, use `'a'` and `'z'` since it will be clearer what the code does, and more portable.

Comment: Well then, i'll try to explain it:

Comment: first of all it works. second i sure did my research but i dont have any knowledge except "hello world" in c programming plus basic arithmetic operators ...  so dont bash the newbies... thx.

Comment: Why the wacky indentation?

Comment: This isn't about "bashing the newbies", it's about fighting academic dishonesty. If you had really written this code then you'd know how it works. You're literally asking us to explain your own code to you. That's absurd. It's also of zero value for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (str[i])     //While String is true (Still characters left)
```

This is a very common C idiom, but it's actually a tricky piece of code. `i` is your index into the string. When `i` is 0, `str[i]` is the first character of the string (i.e. "first character plus zero characters"). When `i` is 1, it's the second character of the string ("first character plus one character").

A "character" in C is just a number. So the letter "A" happens to be 65. Your string is:

```
char str[]="My hovercraft is full of eels.";
```

So this is really an array of numbers. What's not obvious is that C automatically appends a zero to the end of the string. So this is really just a convenience for:

```
char str[] = { 'M', 'y', ' ', 'h', ... 'l', 's', '.', '\0' };
```

That last `\0` is called `NUL` (or sometimes "null"). It's a character (a "letter"). It just happens to be the character with the value zero. And it marks the end of a string. This "array of byte-sized characters, followed by a `NUL`" is incredibly common in C, and is widely called a cstring ("C string"), even when it shows up in other languages. This is *not* the only way to represent strings, but it is by far the most common in C, and it's what you get when you use the `"..."` syntax.

So each character is a number, and the last character is zero. Now we use another common C idiom: zero is false, all other values are true. So `while (str[i])` is equivalent to:

```
while (str[i] != 0)
```

or even more precisely:

```
while (str[i] != '\0')
```

Which is an insanely long-winded way of saying "until `i` refers to the end of the string."

(Don't despair. The rest is surprising simple compared to that first line. But that first line is incredibly common in C, so you need to understand all the little things that are happening.)

```
if (str[i]!='z')   //if character is NOT "z" shift character by one
```

Easy-peasy. If the current character we're looking at isn't a `z`... "We're looking at" is defined by `i`.

```
(c=str[i]+1);
```

Don't know why there are parentheses here. That's kind of unusual. But the point is to just take the character we're looking at, and add one to the numeric representation of it, and assign that to `c`. Since both ASCII and UTF8 (two very common ways to encode strings) put the Latin alphabet in order, "a+1" is "b".

Note that this is *not* implementing a proper Caesar cipher. In a traditional Caesar cipher with offset 1, "Z" would shift to "A". In this cipher, "Z" will shift to "[". But I'm being pedantic. It's just worth understanding that this cipher has some surprising corner cases. For instance, it will encode both `z` and backtick `` ` `` as `a`, so it can technically lose information and cannot be reversed over arbitrary ASCII input (it's completely broken for UTF8 input, so we won't even discuss that here). Not a big deal, but as programmers, corner cases are our lives, so it's good to know what inputs this works for and what inputs it does not work for.

```
(c=str[i]='a'); //if character equals "z" then the output is "a"
```

This line is almost certainly a bug. The parentheses are weird again, but not a problem. The problem with this line of code is that it modifies `str`, which the previous code did not. Almost certainly this code should read:

```
c = 'a';
```

When the current character is `z`, the output should be `a`.

```
printf("%c" ,c);  // Shows encrypted string
```

The comment here is a little misleading. It should say "shows encrypted character."

```
i++;
```

And we move our index forward one character before starting the process again. `i++` is just a C-ism for `i = i + 1`. (It's slightly more complicated than that when it appears inside of an expression, but in this case, you could exactly replace it with `i = i + 1`.)

```
return 0;
```

And in the Unix style (which C is deeply entwined with), `main()` returns zero to mean "no error."

Comment: thx man, thats way more into detail than i expected, thanks alot for your time! A+ for effort :D  i edited it without brackets and replaced c='a'; so thanks for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is that it accesses each letter in the while loop and is referenced whe `str[i]` is used. Then if the letter is not z it moves it one letter up the alphabet so `abc` returns `bcd`. Then, if the letter is z, it becomes a.

You can slightly modify the program to decrypt the output by changing `str[i]+1` to -1 and switching